# How to Play dynamic video into flowlayer

Tags: php, flowplayer

Here is my :

```
<?php
if($total_count > 0)
{
   while($val =$objDB->get_row($rs_member))
  {
 // $flowplayer = "player".$val['video_id'];
 $VideoPath = "uploadedvideo/video/".$val['video'];
?>
<div style="border:#FF0000;">
   <div id="video1">
        <a href="<?=$VideoPath?>" 
    style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px;" 
    id="player">
   </a>
        <!-- this will install flowplayer inside previous A- tag. -->
    <script>
                        flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.2.5.swf",  {
    clip: {
        // these two configuration variables does the trick
        url: '<?=$VideoPath?>',
        autoPlay: false, 
        autoBuffering: true // <- do not place a comma here  
    }
});
        </script>




     </div>
    </div> 
<?php
  }
}
?>
```

Instead of this I need to play all video file in a single page serially..how to do this..please help

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an array of all the videos you want to play and then add them to a playlist, like so:

```
<?php
if($total_count > 0)
{
  $Videos = array();
   while($val =$objDB->get_row($rs_member))
  {
 // $flowplayer = "player".$val['video_id'];
 $Videos[] = "uploadedvideo/video/".$val['video'];
  }
  $VideoPlaylist = "'" . implode("', '", $Videos) . "'"; // will look something like : 'vid1.fla', 'vid2.fla'
?>
<div style="border:#FF0000;">
   <div id="video1">
        <a 
    style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px;" 
    id="player">
   </a>
        <!-- this will install flowplayer inside previous A- tag. -->
    <script>
                        flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.2.5.swf",  {
    clip: {
        // these two configuration variables does the trick
        autoPlay: false, 
        autoBuffering: true // <- do not place a comma here  
    },
    playlist: [<?php echo $VideoPlaylist; ?>]
});
        </script>




     </div>
    </div> 
<?php
  }
?>
```